# jQuery not working within Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have this bit of jQuery script that can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/RUqNN/45/

When I incorporate this script into my wordpress template, I doesn't work.

I've check the jquery source link, rewritten the code, nothing works.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $(".move").toggle(
            function() {
              $("#teetimetag").animate({
                right: "0px"
              }, "normal");
            },function() {
              $("#teetimetag").animate({
                right: "-200px"
              }, "normal");
          });
        });
    </script>
      <div id="teetimetag">
         <img class="move" src="http://test.tooheavytoskydive.com/wp-content/themes/newtheme/images/flag.png" style="float: left;" />
        <div style="margin: 15px 0 0 50px;">
          <a href="http://test.tooheavytoskydive.com/reservations/" style="color: #FFF; font-weight: bold; font-size: 17px;">Reserve your Tee-Time</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Is this using the free version of wordpress? Do they restrict adding your own js?

Comment: Is is the free version.  I've never heard to them restricting JS.  I use tons of plugins that use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your website gives the following javascript error: '$ is not a function'. It looks like jQuery conflicts with some other library. This can be solved by calling jQuery.noConflict() and replacing all $ with 'jQuery'. The code will look as follows:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          jQuery(".move").toggle(
            function() {
              jQuery("#teetimetag").animate({
                right: "0px"
              }, "normal");
            },function() {
              jQuery("#teetimetag").animate({
                right: "-200px"
              }, "normal");
          });

});
```

Comment: Any degubbing tools/tips on finding out what is causing the conflict?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a tool. You can disable plugins and see where the problem is.
In your case the problem seems to be in the Booking Calendar Scripts, where you define 'var jWPDev = jQuery.noConflict();'. When you use noConflict, the $ is unset. That is the reason, why the error '$ is not a function' appeared.

Comment: Well, currently the functionality of $ is put into the variable jWPDev. You can either use 'jWPDev' instead of $, or remove that line such that $ will be the original function. Keep in mind if you delete that line you need to change all occurences of jWPDev into $ (Which I think is only used at the bottom of the file wp-content/plugins/booking/js/datepick/jquery.datepick.js).
To find this, I just looked through all javascript on your website, looking for what might cause the conflict (basically looking for the $ in your code).

Answer (score 0):

you should register you js files in your template functions.php file:

```
wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js');
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script

Comment: Where should that call be located?  In the functions file or in the header?

Comment: in your functions.php, it will be called by using wp add_action() function, you can control how and for which pages it should be called, read this part of wp documentation for more information: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript

Answer (score -1):

As a general rule, you should not use the `$` variable for `jQuery` unless you have used one of the [shortcuts](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries#Referencing_Magic_-_Shortcuts_for_jQuery). The following is an example of how to shortcut jQuery to safely use the `$` variable:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    /* You can safely use $ in this code block to reference jQuery */
});
```

To load jquery at wordpress use the either one of the following 2 versions. Include the  code at `Plugin Page` OR at `function.php`

```
function include_jQuery() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'include_jQuery');
```

Definitely you can use any meaningful function name instead off `include_jQuery`.

Alternately, you can use the following code:

```
function include_jQuery() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        // comment out the next two lines to load the local copy of jQuery
        wp_deregister_script('jquery'); 
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js', false, '1.8.3'); 
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'include_jQuery');
```

You may like [THIS](http://www.ericmmartin.com/5-tips-for-using-jquery-with-wordpress/) link as well from where I personally learn the above technique(s). A Very BIG Thanks to **Ericm Martin!**