# jquery requires the word Jquery instead of $

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress theme and I have included Jquery,

```
    // Waves
    wp_enqueue_style( 'APKMirror-wave', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/waves/waves.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'APKMirror-wave',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/inc/waves/waves.min.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );

    // Boostrap
    wp_enqueue_style( 'APKMirror-Bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'APKMirror-Bootstrap',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/inc/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
```

The problem is any time I run jQuery code I have to type the word 'jQuery' instead of just using the $. How can I change my code so that it will use $?

Comment: http://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/

Comment: [Duplicate 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25128736/unable-to-use-get-within-wordpress-page/25128843#25128843) [Duplicate 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090615/javascript-not-loading-wordpress-footer/25090781#25090781) [Duplicate 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273501/why-isnt-enqueued-script-in-wordpress-working/25274220#25274220) [Duplicate 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154218/jquery-not-working-within-wordpress) etc. Most of these answers are by @NathanDawson - surprised he didn't flag this himself...

Comment: Glad I was not the only one asking this question lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery in WordPress runs in noConflict mode which means the global $ shortcut for jQuery isn't available. Use the document ready wrapper which will allow $ to be used as an alias for jQuery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Inside here $ can be used instead of jQuery.
});
```

Or

```
(function($) {
    // Use $ here.
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks to **Paulpro** for correctly pointing out that there is an alternative that can be used if you need to run the script before the rest of the DOM loads.

Comment: You can also use `jQuery(function($) { ... });`

Comment: -1, because you assume the OP's script should wait until the DOM is ready to run. Some scripts are important to run before the rest of DOM starts loading. If you show an alternative that doesn't wait until the DOM is ready to run, such as `(function($) { // Use $ here  })(jQuery);`, I will switch the -1 to a +1.

Comment: @Paulpro -  I was weighing up whether to add this alternative to the answer when writing it but you're quite right. The answer has been modified.