# Use jquery datepicker in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, datepicker

I want datepicker to who in a form in my wordpress template page, but it doesn't work.

This is the code I've the child theme functions.php:

```
function modify_jquery() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        // comment out the next two lines to load the local copy of jQuery
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js', false, '2.1.1');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'modify_jquery');
function load_jquery_ui_google_cdn() {
    global $wp_scripts;

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-slider');

    // get the jquery ui object
    $queryui = $wp_scripts->query('jquery-ui-core');

    // load the jquery ui theme
    $urlui = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.8/jquery-ui.min.js";
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-smoothness', $urlui, false, null);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_jquery_ui_google_cdn');
```

Then I've this in page-mypage.php:

```
                <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
                </script>
...other code...
Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker">
...other code...
        </form>
```

But it doesn't show. Could you help me to wind what's wrong?

Comment: Your jQuery URL looks wrong (you have `ajax.googleapis.com/ajax.googleapis.com`).  Have you included `datepicker()` anywhere?  I think it's part of jQuery UI, not base jQuery

Comment: @Hobo Thanks for your reply, I've added jQueryi UI as showed in first post, but still it doesn't work,

Comment: Isn't it better to use "WP Datepicker' plugin in WordPress?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The code you're using to load jQuery is invalid and you aren't loading datepicker (jQuery UI Datepicker) at all. I've posted a few answers regarding the correct way to use jQuery in WordPress so I'll provide a working example and then a link if you'd like to read more.

Replace the code you've inserted into your child theme functions.php with:

```
/**
 * Load jQuery datepicker.
 *
 * By using the correct hook you don't need to check `is_admin()` first.
 * If jQuery hasn't already been loaded it will be when we request the
 * datepicker script.
 */
function wpse_enqueue_datepicker() {
    // Load the datepicker script (pre-registered in WordPress).
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );

    // You need styling for the datepicker. For simplicity I've linked to the jQuery UI CSS on a CDN.
    wp_register_style( 'jquery-ui', 'https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui' );  
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_enqueue_datepicker' );
```

Finally replace your usage with:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

[jquery requires the word Jquery instead of $](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320795/jquery-requires-the-word-jquery-instead-of/25320826#25320826)

Comment: it's starting to work, thank you! Now I see the calendar on trasparent background. How to have the default layout like here? http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default

Comment: I've gone ahead and updated my answer to include details regarding loading the jQuery UI stylesheet.

Comment: I've tested your update, cleared the cache, but still transparent background. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: My apologies, I should have checked the CSS file first. Please retry with the updated link.

Comment: Google hosted theme also: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css from: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery-ui

Comment: Master - save me a lot time :)

Answer (score 8):

For loading bellows script & style add bellows code on theme functions.php file.

**Script for front-end use**

```
function add_e2_date_picker(){
//jQuery UI date picker file
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
//jQuery UI theme css file
wp_enqueue_style('e2b-admin-ui-css','http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css',false,"1.9.0",false);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_e2_date_picker');
```

**Script for back-end use**

```
    function add_e2_date_picker(){
    //jQuery UI date picker file
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
    //jQuery UI theme css file
    wp_enqueue_style('e2b-admin-ui-css','http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css',false,"1.9.0",false);
    }
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_e2_date_picker');
```

Just put this code also funtions.php file or bellow those code.

```
function register_datepiker_submenu() {
    add_submenu_page( 'options-general.php', 'Date Picker', 'Date Picker', 'manage_options', 'date-picker', 'datepiker_submenu_callback' );
}

function datepiker_submenu_callback() { ?>

    <div class="wrap">

    <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="datepicker" value=""/>

    </div>

    <script>
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat : "dd-mm-yy"
        });
    });
    </script> 

<?php }
add_action('admin_menu', 'register_datepiker_submenu');
?>
```

After adding this code, you’ll got a date picker on Admin **Menu->Settigns->Date Picker**.

Please see details on [Add a jQuery DatePicker to WordPress Theme or Plugin](http://www.e2soft.com/blog/add-a-jquery-date-picker-to-wordpress-theme-or-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

A more easy solution would be:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myScripts');
function myScripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('my_script', script.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-datepicker'));
}
```

And the `script.js` file would have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker();
});
```